# Ubuntu Server 17.04 unable to locate package libapache2-svn

Tags: server, svn

Been trying to install `libapache2-svn` for hours using the command `sudo apt-get install libapache2-svn` but no luck it gives me the error (unable to locate package libapache2-svn) over and over again.
I've tried updating the ubuntu server many times but still gives the same error.

Thanks in advance.

P.S if libapache2-svn repository is not available for 17.04 is there a way to install it then for 17.04?

Comment: Please enable `trusty-updates` and `trusty-updates` in `system settings --> software & updates`

Comment: I'm a bit confused - your title indicates version 17.04, and the tag is version 14.04.  Please update your question with the output of `uname -r`

Comment: I agree with @CharlesGreen please which is it, as I can see it in `Ubuntu Trusty`

Comment: my bad. Removed the 14.04 in the tags. Can you confirm if libapache2-svn is included in 17.04?

Answer (score 11):

I don't know about 17.04, but in 18.04, the package is called [libapache2-mod-svn](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/libapache2-mod-svn)

Answer (score 1):

Please check and make sure these `trusty-updates` and `trusty-updates` are enabled in your `system settings` like the image below:

[image]

See my out when I search for it:

```
george@george-VirtualBox:~$ apt search libapache2-svn
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libapache2-svn/trusty-updates,trusty-security 1.8.8-1ubuntu3.2 all
  Apache Subversion server modules for Apache httpd (dummy package)
```

Comment: I think that the tag indicating version 14.04 is incorrect, and queried the op on that.  `libapache2-svn` is not included in the 17.04 repositories.

Comment: Yes just saw your query.

Answer (score 1):

libapache2-svn is just a dummy package for installing Apache Subversion server modules for Apache httpd (*libapache2-mod-svn*). libapache2-svn is not available in the 17.04 repositories, but you don't need to install this dummy package, install libapache2-mod-svn without installing the dummy package instead.

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-svn
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file for the "http://" with "ftp://" and then run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-cache search subversion` if results are found then proceed installation with `sudo apt-get install subversion` or else run `sudo apt-cache search libapache2-svn` then if results are found here then do a `sudo apt-cache install libapache2-svn`.

Comment: Still doesnt work. I tried running sudo apt-cache search libapache2-svn but no results found but i still tried running sudo apt-cache install libapache2-svn but it returned an error "Invalid operation install", I then tried sudo apt-get install libapache2-svn but still returns an error "Unable to locate package libapache2-svn"

Comment: @Supremo try the source list generator https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ and then try update and then install, proceed with caution although. If there is something you do not know what you are doing simply stop and ask the same question on serverFault or refer to https://serverfault.com/questions/209055/ubuntu-unable-to-install-libapache2-svn

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main  
sudo add-apt-repository universe 
sudo add-apt-repository restricted  
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```